# How to send firebase push notification from node server

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using nodeJS and mongodb as a backend service in my android app and using 
FCM for sending push notifications to users.
To achieve this I am saving firebase registration token on MongoDb.

I want to send push notifications to the corresponding user when they added data on MongoDb server.

This is my code below to add data on database.

```
router.post('/addbooks', (req,res) => {

var data = {

    Reg_token: req.body.token,
    Email:req.body.email,
    Name: req.body.name
  };

  MongoClient.connect(dburl, {useNewUrlParser:true} ,(err,client) => {

          if(err){

            console.log("Error".red, +err);
          }
          else{

            var collect = client.db('My_db').collection('Users');

            collect.insertOne(data, (err,resp) =>{

                  if(err){

                    console.log("Error".red, +err);
                  }
                  else{

                    console.log("Successfully inserted");
                  }

                  client.close();
            });

        }

    });

 });
```

Now as soon as data added in database I want to send notification to the users.Someone please let me know how can I achieve desired task.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Are you looking for something like mongo's change-streams? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/

Comment: No not change streams I want to send firebase push notifications

Comment: So, is this question about mongo at all? I'm a little confused. If you use the [firebase npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) you should be able to send a push to a user

Answer (score 1):

For any one else who may be having this problem,

Basically the implementation needs to be something like this: The user data object in your MongoDB has the FCM token also stored. So when a user adds data, the token is fetched and based on your Firebase JSON config in your node app, the push notification is sent to the actual device that was registered using the FCM token.

You can check out this tutorial from Julla Inc for a full explanation and sample code

https://medium.com/@jullainc/firebase-push-notifications-to-mobile-devices-using-nodejs-7d514e10dd4